# Can I embed a wolfram script in a RxJS or RxJava iterator method?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I need to inject Wolfram script code in embeddable javascript or compiled native bytecode into an iterator in RxJava or RxJS. Is this possible with either a third-party vendor solution or Wolfram service?

Tried looking for Wolfram script to java cross-compilation or JS compilation.

```
\[Sum](x[i])
```

on an array x[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
an iterator on x of /[SUM] should yield 45

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with the Wolfram, but a quick read of their documentation makes it seem pretty obvious that the Wolfram Engine is a bit too heavy-weight to run in a browser.

It looks like you'll have to run your scripts on the server side, and communicate via an api.